# Clear chat after few id-s are inserted

Tags: timer, chat

i made a simple chat, and i want to make when there is total 5 messages (id's) the chat will start the timer (5 seconds) and will clear all rows. This is what i've made.

I have this to check if we reached 5 messages (id's)

```
if($handler->lastInsertId() == 5){
     clearchat_time();
}
```

I used "lastInsertId()" because i don't know how to call a function to count all rows, so i use this one with checking id. If you know how to do this, this would be better solution for me.

So...that will check and call this:

```
<script>
function clearchat_time(){
    setInterval(count_chat_time, 5000);
}
function count_chat_time(){
    $sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE chat";
    $query = $handler->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't define the versions of PHP, JavaScript or SQL -- so I am assuming PHP because of the dollar signs in the question (with some JavaScript concern about the "<script>" tag in the second part of the example) and MySQL, since that is most common with PHP in a LAMP stack.`

Using SQL auto-insert IDs in this way may not be portable to other SQLs is potentially untrustworthy since ([given the various dialects of SQL](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)) the IDs are not guaranteed to always be sequential, nor that the latest one is the highest.  Additionally if the database & table were set up by others, you cannot assume that the increment is only by one, or that it starts at one (1).

It is probably safer to check the actual total number of rows in the table as below:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total from chat");
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $data['total'];
```